# How to sort parts of table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a table in Matlab containing test data from different test persons. The test has seven video clips each with four different audio versions, which the test persons must rate on a scale from 1 to 100. Every video clip is presented twice for statistical accuracy. The test person pushes buttons 1-4 on an interface to hear the different audio versions.

My table contains the following columns (among some others that are not relevant for the question):

```
Test Person ID        Audio Version     Video Clip   Rating
               1            1           Forest       40
               1            2           Forest       60
               1            3           Forest       20
               1            4           Forest       100
```

Now, to introduce minimal bias towards any favor of a particular button during the test, the audio versions are randomly permuted between every video clip. This means the real data will look somewhat more like this (Audio Version not sorted):

```
Test Person ID      Audio Version       Video Clip  Rating
               1            1           Forest      40
               1            2           Forest      60
               1            3           Forest      20
               1            4           Forest      100
               1            3           City        10
               1            2           City        50
               1            1           City        40
               1            4           City        7
               1            4           Inside      90
               1            2           Inside      58
               1            1           Inside      22
               1            3           Inside      35
```

**What I want to do is to: Maintain the correct order of the video clips, thus still have Forest -> City -> Inside, but have them all ordered so that is always audio version 1, 2, 3, 4:**

```
Test Person ID      Audio Version       Video Clip  Rating
               1            1           Forest      40
               1            2           Forest      60
               1            3           Forest      20
               1            4           Forest      100
               1            1           City        40
               1            2           City        50
               1            3           City        10
               1            4           City        7
               1            1           Inside      22
               1            2           Inside      58
               1            3           Inside      35
               1            4           Inside      90
```

My initial thought was to use the `sortrow()` function in Matlab and then sort them ascendingly along with the video clip, but since the video clips are introduced twice at different stages of the test and I want to maintain the same sequence of the clips in the table this doesn’t work. Also the same video clips are presented to numerous different test persons.

I am using a pre-made function that has to have the data sorted in this way to perform statistical calculations on it. This function takes the Matlab data from a struct and puts it into the table via a for-loop row for row.

Because the data is put into the table via a for-loop I thought there might be a way to only *sort a fixed number of rows at a time* i.e row 1-4, 5-8, 9-12 and so on. **Do you know if there is a way to sort only part of a table in Matlab?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reshape` and `sort` you can do:

```
[~,idx]=sort(reshape(Audio_Version,4,[]));
idxtble = bsxfun(@plus,idx,0:4:(4*size(idx,2))-1);
table2 = table1(idxtble,:);
```

Explanation:

You can extract the audio column and reshape it to to [4 * n] matrix:

```
audio =  reshape(Audio_Version,4,[]);
```

then sort columns of audio and get indexes of sorted elements:

```
[~,idx]=sort(audio);
```

Here `idx` represents row numbers of the sorted elements.

Convert `idx` to linear indexes of the whole column of the table:

```
 idxtbl = bsxfun(@plus,idx,0:4:(4*size(idx,2))-1);
```

Reorder the table:

```
table2 = table1(idxtbl,:);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I get the expected output from idx i.e. a lot of 4 row columns that contain the indexes from 1-4 according to the order in my table. I don't fully understand the second line though with 'idxtble' though.
When I try to run the line it says "Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other". I removed the increment of four thus changing the line to `idxtble = bsxfun(@plus,idx,0:4:size(idx,2)-1);` (what I think was your original answer), but when I do that I end up with table2 being a single numerical value.

Comment: @matiastofteby Sorry for late reply. you are right.answer updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The updated version worked just as I hoped. I have now accepted your answer. Have a great day.

Comment: Glad if I can help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single call to [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) by creating an additional numeric column representing your fixed pattern of video presentations. This additional column will simply label each set of 4 rows with a successive integer. It can be [concatenated to the beginning of the table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-and-delete-table-variables.html#zmw57dd0e24904), then you can sort by the first and third columns to get the ordering you want:

```
[~, index] = sortrows([table(ceil((1:size(T, 1)).'./4)) T], [1 3]);
T = T(index, :);
```

And the output:

```
T = 

    ID    Audio     Video      Rating
    __    _____    ________    ______

    1     1        'Forest'     40   
    1     2        'Forest'     60   
    1     3        'Forest'     20   
    1     4        'Forest'    100   
    1     1        'City'       40   
    1     2        'City'       50   
    1     3        'City'       10   
    1     4        'City'        7   
    1     1        'Inside'     22   
    1     2        'Inside'     58   
    1     3        'Inside'     35   
    1     4        'Inside'     90
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer - it surely looks clean and simple. However, I am not completely sure with your use of 'T' vs. table in this example. If table is my already excisting table then where/how do I declare T?

Comment: @matiastofteby: `T` is your existing table. Just replace it with whatever variable stores your table.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `sortrow` for the specified part of the table like the following:

```
table(1:4,:) = sortrow(table(1:4,:), 2);
table(4:8,:) = sortrow(table(4:8,:), 2);
table(8:12,:) = sortrow(table(8:12,:), 2);
```

First sort the part of the table, then replace it with that part.